Criteria for transitivity
I am reading R. Dixon's work on ergativity. He employs three basic syntactic relations:

S for a single argument of a verb
A for one argument of a verb
O for the other argument of a verb

In an ergative language like Basque a transitive verb can be identified by checking whether there is Ergative in a sentence. The following examples are extracted from a machine translator:
Johnek hil zaitu (John killed you)
John erori egin da (John fell)
John Moskura joan zen (John went to Moscow)
However, when it comes to accusative languages, how can one know if a given verb is transitive or not? One possible evidence comes from passivisation but it is now always reliable (cf. to have in English, знать, целовать in Russian, etc.)
I looked at Swahili which has polypersonal agreement: object agreement does not operate exclusively on what can be traditionally called direct object (wa- and tu- are object markers for you and we respectively):
Yohana akamwambia (John said it to you)
Yohana alituambia (John said it to us)
but Yohana alikwenda kwetu (John went to us)
One may define O to mean that an entity is affected by an action so that the addressee and the killed are both taken to be O. But then the verb to laugh can also be said to be transitive as one of its agruments gets affected by someone doing the laughing. What I mean is that we can find verbs one of whose arguments can be interpreted as O but is marked by an adposition or different case (e.g., помогать кому-то (to help someone-DAT) in Russian) unlike other insances of the realisation of O.
My question is: for an accusative language, are there any criteria that allow to distinguish between intransitive and transitive verbs?
Thank you!

There is no sharp distinction. Hopper & Thompson 1980, Transitivity in grammar and discourse, in Language 56(2) is a great place to start.

@Keelan, Are you talking about accusative langauges?

Yes, did you have a look at the article?

@Keelan, I did. Thanks! I looked through the first couple of pages. Does the article contain any information on non-trivial syntactic features of transitive verbs (an example of a trivial feature would be passivisation)?

Well, for a start, section 2.1 promises "morphosyntactic reflexes of Transitivity".

If a transitive verb in Basque can be identified by the presence of the ergative in a sentence, couldn't a transitive verb in Latin equally be identified by the presence of the accusative?

@Draconis, yeah, ACC is a sign of O. As Dixon says on p. 52 in "Ergativity', when there are just 2 arguments, one of them will be mapped onto O. So I am concerned with cases when the 2nd argument is not marked with ACC (e.g., the Russian verbs помогать and управлять that take DAT and INSTR respectively). If O is only confined to ACC, then these verbs are intransitive and the arguments will not be core (which is not the case).

In Japanese, を is usually accusative case particle marking direct object of transitive verb, but を is also used with some intransitive motion verbs (see also here).
